# No option to choose Ubuntu - boots into windows

Tags: dual-boot, gparted, bootloader

After installing Ubuntu and going through the process after restarting It boots immediately into windows.

I’m currently in the try Ubuntu and this is the gparted that I got right now.
I tried running boot-repair with no help.
[image]

Appreciate any help or input

Comment: Based on the picture of gparted, Ubuntu is not installed.

Comment: Did you "install Ubuntu" to a Windows `:`, `D:` or `E:` drive? That won't work - ever. It would require booting Windows before Ubuntu could boot.

Comment: It says that it was installed successfully. I installed it on my HDD D: drive allocated 600gb and windows is on my SSD C: drive. When I run Ubuntu from USB it says to reinstall Ubuntu so I would assume it’s already installed

Comment: Try boot-repair from a live USB.